# Recyclerview DiffUtil scrolls my list to top when updated

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I've decided to give `DiffUtil` a try instead of `notifyDataSetChanged` in my `EndlessRecyclerView`.

The problem is, after the first or second fling my `list` is scrolled to top, but the items are added to the list.

Here's my `DiffUtil`:

```
    public class MovieDiffCallback extends DiffUtil.Callback {

    List<Movie> mOldMovieList;
    List<Movie> mNewMovieList;

    public MovieDiffCallback(List<Movie> oldMovieList, List<Movie> newMovieList) {
        this.mOldMovieList = oldMovieList;
        this.mNewMovieList = newMovieList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getOldListSize() {
        return mOldMovieList != null ? mOldMovieList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getNewListSize() {
        return mNewMovieList != null ? mNewMovieList.size() : 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areItemsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return mOldMovieList.get(oldItemPosition).getId().equals(mNewMovieList.get(newItemPosition).getId());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean areContentsTheSame(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return mOldMovieList.get(oldItemPosition).equals(mNewMovieList.get(newItemPosition));
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getChangePayload(int oldItemPosition, int newItemPosition) {
        return super.getChangePayload(oldItemPosition, newItemPosition);
    }
}
```

And this is where I use it in my `Fragment`:

```
@Override
public void getMovies(List<Movie> moviesList) {
    mDiffCallback = new MovieDiffCallback(mMoviesList, moviesList);
    mDiffResult = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(mDiffCallback);
    mMoviesList.addAll(moviesList);
    mDiffResult.dispatchUpdatesTo(mAdapter);
    isLoadedLandscape = true;
}
```

And this is in the `EndlessRecyclerScroll`:

```
            @Override
            public void onLoadMore(int page, int totalItemsCount, RecyclerView view) {
                scrollPage++;
                populateMap(scrollPage);
                mPresenter.getSuggestedMovies(searchParamsMap);
            }
```

Comment: no need for `DiffUtil` - if you are getting N new items and already have M items then just call `notifyItemRangeInserted(M, N)`

Comment: What would be the best practice? `M = mMoviesList.size()` and after adding the new items `N = mMoviesList.size()`?

Comment: if you already have 1000 items and you get 5 new items just call `notifyItemRangeInserted(1000, 5)`

Comment: Items are dynamic, I can't just call `notifyItemRangeInserted(1000, 5)`

Comment: i know that items are dynamic thats why  i used N and M in my first comment

Comment: And that's why I asked you whether this is the best approach (my first comment).

Comment: so whats unclear actually in `"if you are getting N new items and already have M items then just call notifyItemRangeInserted(M, N)"` ? for example you already have  1000 items and you are getting 5 new items you call `notifyItemRangeInserted(1000, 5)` next time you call `notifyItemRangeInserted(1005, 5)` etc